# Wikipedia / MediaWiki Search API → query urls

Tags: api, search, mediawiki, wikipedia

I want to search Wikipedia for a link.
Unfortunately it uses the dot as a wildcard in the search query:

**Example:**
http://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=%22chatroulette.de%22&srprop=timestamp
= finds `chatroulette de la...`

**API:**
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search

Who has an idea, whats wrong here?
Is there a parameter i forgot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for the [linksearch API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aExturlusage).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly there is no way how to use wildcards in your search phrase